# How to consume java REST webservice in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, rest, windows-phone-8

I am trying to consume Java REST Webservice in windows phone 8.But it is always giving 404 (page not found) exception (system.net.http.httpexception).That means not able to connect to webservice.

Following is the client code which i used for consuming webservice.

```
try
{
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
String result = await http.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.0.56:8078/sample/page/name");

MessageBox.Show(result);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 error - file not found, connection works

Comment: but that webservice is working fine.But iam not able to make a connection from windows phone app to webservice.

Comment: @Salman Try and see whether you can reach the service via browser on the device/emulator. It may be just the the resource isn't accessible to the device/emulator.

Comment: @akshay2000 Iam not able to access the webservice via browser in emulator.Not even any website.

Comment: Maybe the Emulator didn't install properly to encapsulate the physical network adapter

Comment: @verdesrobert yeah..That was the prob.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.Emulator was not able to connect to internet,which was the problem.I tried in windows phone and its working fine.Thanks @akshay2000.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Network Adapters and Verify that there are Hyper-V in their names or 'v' prefixes on the Adapter names, if there are you should check if they are enabled, and enable them if disabled.
If you have nothing like that you should repair the sdk, and that will fix the issue.